# What is the meaning of "constituent" in this phrase?

Tags: meaning

Site Location : This is a process that organizations use to identify retail locations most suitable to the "**constituent customer profiles** ".

Comment: Soudabeh, what have you already found out about the word "constituent"?

Comment: 1-being part of a whole 2- being a voting member in an organization @Magana! But I cannot understand its  relation with customer profiles!

Answer (score 2):

I can see your problem, Soudabeh, I've spent some time tracking down the meaning I think "constituent" has in this context. I don't know why it took so long.

My take is that the **constituent customer profiles** here are profiles of the customers who are likely to visit the "retail locations" mentioned earlier. In this sense, "constituent" means

> 1. serving to make up a thing; component: the constituent parts of a motor. - *[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/constituent)*

The "constituent customers" are those who make up the "customer base" of retail locations.

(I have to say this is the kind of management speak up with which I will not put)

Comment: @Soudabeh: I suspect that "main customers' profiles" may overstate the importance of some of the individuals included in this group. I would not be surprised if any "regular" or "established" customer of a retailer qualifies as a "constituent," as the term is being used here—and yet a customer may be regular (that is, may come back to the retailer periodically) without being a "main customer" (that is, one who contributes substantially to the retailers profits over the course of a year). So I would vote for "regular [or _established_] customers' profiles" as the translation.